# How to add text to Arcore 3D object using openGL without using Sceneform?

Tags: java, opengl-es, arcore, glsurfaceview, sceneform

I am working on AR core android and i want to put text Label on touch. I am successfully able to put object on surface using openGL and GLsurfaceview but i want to add text Label on surface and i don't want to use Sceneform.

In Sceneform  i am able to do it like this.i want same thing using openGL

```
  private void placeObject(ArFragment fragment, Anchor anchor, Uri model,String myText) {

    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.text_view, null);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, 10);
    params.setMargins(45, 0, 5, 0);

    TextView dynamicTextBackground = new TextView(this);
    dynamicTextBackground.setLayoutParams(params);
    dynamicTextBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    dynamicTextBackground.setText("1");
    dynamicTextBackground.setTextSize(1);

    TextView dynamicTextView = new TextView(this);

    dynamicTextView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    dynamicTextView.setText(myText);
    dynamicTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    dynamicTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    dynamicTextView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);


    dynamicTextBackground.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.badge_circle));
    linearLayout.addView(dynamicTextBackground);
    linearLayout.addView(dynamicTextView);



    ViewRenderable.builder()
            .setView(this,linearLayout)
            .build()
            .thenAccept(renderable -> addNodeToScene(fragment, anchor, renderable))
            .exceptionally((throwable -> {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage(throwable.getMessage())
                        .setTitle("Error!");
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
                return null;
            }));

}
```

Comment: hello , were you able to solve this using opengl ? If yes ,can you please share the code ?